# Open com port in php

Tags: php, serial-port, usb, modem

I have a usb 3G modem Huawei E1550 and Windows XP.
I want to send sms with this modem trhow php.

I use this function to open a modem com port:

```
$fp = fopen ("COM3:", "wb+");
if (!$fp) {
    echo "Not open";
} else {
    echo "Open";
}
```

And every time I get a error:

> Warning: fopen(COM3:) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in D:\Apache\htdocs\z91.ru\audio\test.php on line 3

Comment: `fopen ("COM3:", "wb+");` is not able to open "COM3", are you sure this is the right file/stream to open ?

Comment: I find a many examples in google with this file/stream name

Comment: Well maybe that's the problem. Try another number than 3, like "COM1:" or "COM2", who knows.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try removing the colon next to the COMn for this to work

```
exec("mode COM3 BAUD=9600 PARITY=N data=8 stop=1 xon=off");

$fp = fopen ("COM3", "w");
if (!$fp) {
   echo "Not open";
} else {
   echo "Open";
}
```

Comment: Whoever suggested removing the colon **in an edit** abused the edit function.  That entirely changes the theme of the answer, so it should have been posted as a distinct answer rather than an edit.

Comment: In a further (and fortunately rejected) inappropriate third party edit attempt, it was suggested that the mode should perhaps include the binary flag, though this would depend on application need.