# Giving PHP permission to access COM port

Tags: php, modem, 3g

I'm creating a php script that connects to a 3G modem connected via serial connection on COM5.

I'm getting the following error and I believe it is because php does not have r/w access to COM5:

> Warning: fopen(COM5:) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\SMStest\test2.php on line 9

```
// mode com1: BAUD=9600 PARITY=N data=8 stop=1 xon=off
$fp = fopen ("COM5:", "w+");
if (!$fp) {
    echo "Uh-oh. Port not opened.";
} else {
    $e = chr(27);
    $string  = $e . "A" . $e . "H300";
    $string .= $e . "V100" . $e . "XL1SATO";
    $string .= $e . "Q1" . $e . "Z";
    echo $string;
    fputs ($fp, $string );
    fclose ($fp);
}
```

Comment: Yes both with/without the colon no difference, same error.

Comment: I'm clueless, but maybe this can help? http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3679-PHP-Communicate-with-a-serial-port.html

Comment: COM5 is a virtual rather than a physical port: does something like dio_open('COM5:', O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK); work instead of fopen?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920600/open-com-port-in-php

Comment: Also,  it says right there in the error message what's wrong. You're trying to open a file called "COM5:", and there is no such file in the directory your script is running from.

Comment: I tried dio_open but i get Fatal error: "Call to undefined function dio_open()" which is strange as it should be part of the standard library...@Svish COM5: is the virtual serial port that the 3g modem is connected to. It is getting picked up in device manager.

Comment: Also, have you tried accessing the physical device object? I.e. \Device\00000123 (You can find it in device manager, properties, details, physical device object name). Not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: Another thing: this code above is directly from php.net
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: Last thing I can think of, did you try accessing it with "\\.\com5" ?

Comment: Leigh thanks a million, that worked! You can post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to access COM ports on windows, alternatives to your method are opening it with the following paths:

`\Device\00000123` (You can find the correct value in device manager, properties, details, physical device object name)

`\\.\com5` (This is how I would open the port as a file if I was writing a program in C or something)