# Close opened COM port with PHP

Tags: php, php-socket

I run this PHP code to open my COM port. But i got an error

```
Warning: fopen(COM2): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$fp = fopen('COM2', 'w+');
if (!$fp) {

    echo"Port not accessible";
} else {

    echo "port is open";
    set_time_limit(2);
}
```

What should i do? I used `fclose($fp)` function to do it. But it not works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP COM port connection with DIO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589702/php-com-port-connection-with-dio)

Comment: This method is not use DIO. It uses fopen

Comment: As PHP said, you don't have enough rights to open the COM2 port. And `fclose($fp)` is the good way to close your port. You certainly need to run your script as root/admin.

Comment: I have done with this in admin privileges.

Comment: What OS are you running? Do you have any firewalls up?

Comment: fopen(COM2) means windows. You don't know that?

Comment: @Nadishan If you running on linux server (I'm not clear on what system you're running your script) try with this: [PHP Oficial Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php#112243)

Comment: fopen command use different name for COM port on linux.

Comment: Refer to this:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920600/open-com-port-in-php][1]


And [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227219/giving-php-permission-to-access-com-port?lq=1][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920600/open-com-port-in-php
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227219/giving-php-permission-to-access-com-port?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like windows (based at com name). If it's windows try to use full port name:  \.\COM2, or escaping  "\\.\COM2"